# unimaginable power and being

Tags: science-based

We often portray imaginary beings with human or animal features. The knowledge we know and we apply them to our imaginary world. A being with eyes, claws or nose for example are features from what we know.

In the world before big bang, there was a being that does not breathe oxygen, does not drink water, eat, sleep and unlike machine it does not need power to operate and yet it can think or create atoms at will. It can break the rules and law of physics just like blackhole (where all law of physics breaks there), so matters cannot be created nor destoryed theory does not apply to this being. This being also can reproduce at will and it does not age. Let's call this being Dowshing for now. Dowshing is a being that caused big bang in the universe 13.8 billion years ago, and it does not have a goal. It would just wondering around and creating more world like ours. To slip in and out of multi-dimensions and recreate itself through any point in the universe (since nothing is faster than speed of light and universe is so big that it would take extreme long time even traveling at light speed, so to get to places faster is create itself at the destination. Dowshing is deciding to remove multiple galaxies from the world and milky way is on the list.

What would mere human do to stop this kind of destruction?

Comment: Please see our meta post about [unstoppable enemies](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4317/what-to-do-about-unstoppable-questions)

Comment: If the creature is outside of physics, no answer is wrong. You can say you can stop the creature by dancing around naked in a dead whale or by singing a song backwards because it is completely up to you. There are no criteria anymore to say that anything is wrong

Comment: @Raditz_35 - please turn dead whale scheme into an answer.  Include backwards song too, please.

Comment: Downvoted as this is not science-based (as tagged), and - as noted by @Rasitz_35 - cannot be answered objectively: no answer is wrong.

Comment: *Dowshing* is the English phonetic rendering of the being's true Mandarin name, 逗形, Dòu Xíng in Pinyin, pronounced `/tou˥˩.ɕiŋ˧˥/`, and meaning *Funny Shape*.

Comment: `What would mere human do to stop this kind of destruction?` something unimaginable.

Comment: "it does not have a goal" directly conflicts with "Dowshing is deciding to remove multiple galaxies from the world and milky way is on the list.". Isn't making a decision somewhat of a goal? Besides even if Dowshing is destroying galaxies, it is only setting itself back. Dowshing should be able to predict what those galaxies would do and the fact that later down the road Dowshing would later just destroy the galaxy is confusing to say the least. Perhaps your Dowshing should have blown it's divine power making the big bang etc and now Dowshing is in a weak state killing galaxies to get it back

Comment: @Crettig it wont able to predict the future. It just something powerful doesnt mean it can control or have goals for what it did or do so logically. Example... someone dig a hole on the ground then bury it back with no purpose. You cant assume what is there, like predicition you mentioned. If someone won a lottery does it mean they are luckiest person in the world? no we dont define luck based on one event, You see, not everything needs to follow logic. Dowshing doesnt have goal doesnt mean it cant do what it is going to do.

Comment: Are they even aware of the existence of the creature? He might just destroy the galaxy before anyone notice him.

Answer (score 1):

Pray, and hope that God is real and will fight back.

Comment: Except that this "Dowshing" caused the Big Bang, is not bound by the laws of the universe and can create and destroy galaxies. By all standard definitions, "Dowshing" _is_ god.

Comment: A god, perhaps. If there's one there's likely others.

Comment: Hence the small 'g'

Comment: god is a term that human created, it can be many and it can still die. but why do we name it god? if we could just name it some names like dori or zori

Answer (score 0):

Key to this answer is how humans know that Dowshing has this plan.  Communicating with or understanding a being like this is not a trivial matter.  Somehow your human is aware of Dowshing's intent.  The mode of interaction between human and Dowshing will dictate what sort of influence humans might have.

If you can communicate with Dowshing, you might propose a different plan.  If it is a creator it might appreciate creativity.  You might propose a different scale on which to enact a plan, for example removing subatomic particles from around a given atom.  You might propose a different time frame, which is also not specified.  A god-level plan for removal of the Milky Way over the next several billion years may not be cause for cancelling school.

Comment: a logical solution to counter the illogical one wouldnt be better if humans  mimic what it does and become Dowshing themselves? Assuming that you are right about communicating and awareness of human race.

Comment: @logger, I was just going to say that. I think you've answered your own question. The only way to defeat such a being is to become just like, or greater than, it.